# Why exactly does this function return a value to some power? (python 2.7)

Tags: function, python-2.7, for-loop, arguments, exponent

```
def power(num, x = 1):
    result = 1
    for i in range(x):
        result = result * num
    return result
```

So I came across a tutorial on calling functions with 2 arguments and this one in the picture was used as an example to show how you could make a function called power(num, x=1) that takes an interval in the first argument and raises it to the power of the second argument. Can someone explain in laymen's terms why this happens and what exactly is going on in this function and 'for' loop?

Comment: How do you define a number raised to the x power mathematically?

Comment: And how does that differ from the loop?

Comment: I'm just not seeing how this function translate to that statement

Comment: The number `1` is the multiplicative identity `(n * 1) == n`. For integer exponents, this function multiplies `num` by itself for `x` iterations. Yes, this isn't a great example of loops nor exponentiation, but it works given unstated assumptions regarding the exponent.

Comment: I think I understand. does the line result = (result*num) somehow concatenate num, except instead of adding the num's together by whatever result is you multiply them? so if the first argument is two and the second argument is three your (result = 3), so result=(result*num) would be the same as result=(3*num) which is essentially (num*num*num), or (2*2*2) which equals 8. This checks out because 2^3 is 8. Am I making sense or am I just guessing and getting lucky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `range(x)` is equivalent to `range(0, x)`, and generates a sequence that ranges from `0` to `x - 1`. For example, with `range(3)` you get the sequence 0, 1, and 2, which has three elements. In general, `range(x)` generates a sequence that has `x` elements.

Second, `for i in range(x)` makes `i` iterates throught all the elements of `range(x)`. Since `range(x)` has `x` elements, `i` will iterate through `x` different values, so the statements in the `for` loop will be executed `x` times.

With the above analysis, the body of the `power` function is equivalent to the following:

```
result = 1
result = result * num
result = result * num
    // repeat x times
result = result * num
```

which is equivalent to:

```
result = 1 * num * num * ... * num    // x nums here
```

which, apparently, is `num` raised to the power of `x`.

### Update

Here's how this function works with specific input data. When `num` is 3 and `x` is 4, we have:

```
result = 1
result = result * num  // = 1 * 3 = 3
result = result * num  // = 3 * 3 = 9
reuslt = result * num  // = 9 * 3 = 27
result = result * num  // = 27 * 3 = 81 = 3^4
return result  // 81 is returned
```

We can also show the execution process in more details:

```
result = 1
i = 0  // entering the loop
result = result * num  // = 1 * 3 = 3
i = 1  // the second round of the loop begins
result = result * num  // = 3 * 3 = 9
i = 2  // the third round of the loop begins
reuslt = result * num  // = 9 * 3 = 27
i = 3  // the fourth and final round of the loop begins
result = result * num  // = 27 * 3 = 81 = 3^4
       // range(4) is exhausted, so the loop ends here
return result  // 81 is returned
```

Comment: can you show what you did again in the body of the power function with a specific example like 3^4? I think I get it, I just need to see it with real values to visualize it better